# Is there any shortcut to collapse all groups in outlook for mac?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook

I am using outlook for mac and one feature that I am missing in outlook for mac is that there isn't any shortcut that I am aware about to collapse all groups. Let me know if there is someway by which we can create that shortcut.

Comment: Do you have an arrow over button? Just guessing....